# Create audio element, play it, and then remove element

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I want to create an audio element when a button is clicked, play the audio, and then remove the audio when it is done playing
Here is my code:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("myAudio"); 

function playAudio() { 
  x.play(); 
}
```

```html
<audio id="myAudio">
  <source src="https://padlet-uploads.storage.googleapis.com/446844750/ca57ed6d83fff9890b4c9f2356e4e0c0/Single_Firework___Sound_Effect_HD__1_.mp3" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
<button onclick="playAudio()" type="button">Play Audio</button>
```

If you notice, when you click on the button, it plays the audio, and you have to wait a few seconds before clicking it again. I want it so that you can keep clicking on the button, and the audio will play.

**A perfect example of the code I want is this site: https://airhorner.com/**

**Keep clicking on the airhorn, and it will create an audio element and play it**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I can understand from the link you posted is that you want to replay the audio from the beginning whenever the button is clicked. You can do it by setting the audio's `currentTime` to 0, then playing the audio:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("myAudio"); 

function playAudio() { 
  x.currentTime = 0;
  x.play(); 
}
```

```html
<audio id="myAudio">
  <source src="https://padlet-uploads.storage.googleapis.com/446844750/ca57ed6d83fff9890b4c9f2356e4e0c0/Single_Firework___Sound_Effect_HD__1_.mp3" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
<button onclick="playAudio()" type="button">Play Audio</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the audio file contains a decent amount of mostly-inaudible trailing empty space:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("myAudio"); 

function playAudio() { 
  x.play(); 
}
x.onended = () => console.log('ended');
```

```html
<audio id="myAudio">
  <source src="https://padlet-uploads.storage.googleapis.com/446844750/ca57ed6d83fff9890b4c9f2356e4e0c0/Single_Firework___Sound_Effect_HD__1_.mp3" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
<button onclick="playAudio()" type="button">Play Audio</button>
```

You can forcibly `.pause` the audio before it ends, in addition to resetting the time to 0:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("myAudio"); 

function playAudio() { 
  x.play(); 
  setTimeout(() => {
    x.pause();
    x.currentTime = 0;
  }, 1500);
}
```

```html
<audio id="myAudio">
  <source src="https://padlet-uploads.storage.googleapis.com/446844750/ca57ed6d83fff9890b4c9f2356e4e0c0/Single_Firework___Sound_Effect_HD__1_.mp3" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
<button onclick="playAudio()" type="button">Play Audio</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Before playing you just need to reset your audio runtime:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("myAudio"); 

function playAudio() {
  x.pause();
  x.currentTime = 0;
  x.play(); 
}
```

```html
<audio id="myAudio">
  <source src="https://padlet-uploads.storage.googleapis.com/446844750/ca57ed6d83fff9890b4c9f2356e4e0c0/Single_Firework___Sound_Effect_HD__1_.mp3" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
<button onclick="playAudio()" type="button">Play Audio</button>
```